# one of Tab Bar Controllers linked to different views depend on user log in/out?

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard, uitabbarcontroller, xcode9

I am a beginner in Swift and I created a project that has a Tab Bar, one of the items in the Tab Bar is called account, in this tab I first check if the user login or not and if not it should view the viewcontroller that contain join/login button [as shown in this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PGILW.jpg)
then when the user login it will show accountcontroller [as shown in this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zg0hw.jpg)

I face a difficulty to show tab bar for two viewcontrollers even when I use a navigation controller :(
I try to implement tab bar Programmatically as shown

```
    let homeViewController = HomeViewController()
    homeViewController.tabBarItem = UITabBarItem(title: nil, image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Apatite logo"), tag: 0)
    let searchViewController = SearchViewController()
    searchViewController.tabBarItem = UITabBarItem(title: nil, image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Search "), tag: 1)
    let addToBagViewController = AddToBagViewController()
    addToBagViewController.tabBarItem = UITabBarItem(title: nil, image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Add2Bag"), tag: 2)
    Auth.auth().addStateDidChangeListener { (auth, user) in 
      if user != nil {
        guard var userAccountTableViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "UserLogIn") else {
          return
        }
        userAccountTableViewController = UserAccountTableViewController()
        userAccountTableViewController.tabBarItem = UITabBarItem(title: nil, image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Account"), tag: 3)
        let viewControllerList = [ homeViewController, searchViewController, addToBagViewController, userAccountTableViewController]
        self.viewControllers = viewControllerList

      } else {
        guard var accountNotLogInViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "logInAndJoin") else {
          return
        }
        accountNotLogInViewController = AccountNotLogInViewController()
        accountNotLogInViewController.tabBarItem = UITabBarItem(title: nil, image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Account"), tag: 3)
        self.setViewControllers([homeViewController, searchViewController,addToBagViewController, accountNotLogInViewController], animated: true)

     }
   }
```

but it does not work it shows `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`
seriously I tried to implement it and I can not reach my idea :( any one help me please :(
[storyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hioLf.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see a couple things going on here, some of which could participate in the crash you are seeing, but none are directly linked from what I can tell.

1) Both your `guard` statements instantiate a VC from your storyboard, yet in the next line you actually replace those instantiations (which were successful, since it's a `guard` not an `if`) with "default" code instantiations, not what you want I don't think. I'd do this here:

```
var accountNotLogInViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "logInAndJoin")
if accountNotLogInViewController == nil {
    accountNotLogInViewController = AccountNotLogInViewController()
}
```

Realistically, though, the storyboard instantiation is what you want to work, so you might not need the fallback check.

2) You are instantiating your other view controllers not from storyboard, when they are already in place for you based on your storyboard.

What you really need to be doing is simply replacing the account login view controller with the logged in account view controller if and only if the user is signed in. All that is needed, then, is to use the `setViewControllers` method where you'll simply replace the last element (the non-logged in VC) with the logged in VC should that be necessary.

So the code would be more like the following:

```
Auth.auth().addStateDidChangeListener { (auth, user) in 
  if user == nil {
    var accountNotLogInViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "logInAndJoin") 
    accountNotLogInViewController.tabBarItem = UITabBarItem(title: nil, image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Account"), tag: 3)
    var currentViewControllers = self.viewControllers
    currentViewControllers.removeLast()
    currentViewControllers.append(accountNotLogInViewController)
    self.setViewControllers(currentViewControllers, animated: true)
 }
```

This assumes you have the logged in view controller as the "default" in the storyboard, and that this code is running within the `UITabBarController` class, otherwise you'd just need to access the tab bar to use `setViewControllers`. Hope this helps!

Comment: thanks! but it show me a error `Value of type '[UIViewController]?' has no member 'removeLast'` the screanshot of code: https://ibb.co/k8N8wn and I make the logged in account view controller as root (default) https://ibb.co/iPb42S

Comment: So `currentViewControllers` is an optional array of VCs, so you just need to unwrap it. There's several ways you could do this, either by optionally unwrapping when you grab `self.viewControllers` or by adding a default should that be `nil` by doing `var currentVCs = self.viewControllers ?? []`.

Comment: yes it works big thanks! I appreciate your hard working with me U are saving my life but if U are free I face a problem when the user log in I perform a Segue to  logged in account view controller but it not show me the tab bar :( i used show type to perform it but it not work